# How can I ensure that two adjacent figures and captions are horizontally aligned?

Tags: table-of-contents

The images do not share a horizontal bottom line, and neither do the captions when using:

```
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/im1}
  \captionof{figure}{Long caption ..........................................................................................................................}
  \label{fig:im1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/im2}
  \captionof{figure}{Long caption ...........................................................................................................................}
  \label{fig:im2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way I can make the base of the image, and the top of the captions aligned horizontally?

Comment: use a tabular with p-columns instead of two minipages.

Comment: It could be done with the `floatrow` package.

Comment: @hun welcome to the site -- please have a look athe answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple with the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Meret Oppenheim – Schoolgirl’s Notebook}}{ \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cahier}}
\hfill
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Meret Oppenheim – My Nurse}}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{magouvernante}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
  \caption{Long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption \label{fig:im1}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
  \caption{Long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption long caption \label{fig:im2}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Uhm, the `\includegraphics` inserts images on the baseline, so wrapping those into a `minipage` with `[b]` is rather superfluous. But +1 anyway  `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

two methods -- measure the width of the figure and save it in a `sbox` --or align the `minipages` at the bottom by using the `[b]` option -- result for both is the same

with the `savebox` option

[image]

or with `minipages` bottom aligned and `captionsetup = linewidth`

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}% measure width}
        \begin{minipage}{\wd0}
            \usebox0
            \caption{\blindtext}
        \end{minipage}
        \label{fig:im1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}}
        \begin{minipage}{\wd0}
            \usebox0
            \caption{\blindtext}
        \end{minipage}
        \label{fig:im2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
                \captionsetup{width=\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \caption{\blindtext}
            \label{fig:im1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
                        \captionsetup{width=\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
                    \caption{\blindtext}
            \label{fig:im2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: added above please

Comment: offending portion removed now